# How to make a dynamic GUI which adjust its size accordingly

Tags: matlab, user-interface

In MATLAB GUI, I want the window gets longer or shorter according to the number of inputs. Number of inputs is changable and each input name will be one under the other. I want it gets the most appropriate look. I could not find how to change the size of the windows by code.

The inputs will look like this:

```
inputA
inputB
inputC
inputD
inputE
...
```

Also, I can accept to make this by adjusting the input's text sizes according to the size of the window.(windows size might be constant)

Lastly, I want to learn how to get the size of the GUI window when units is characters or pixels. I think it should has different size when units changes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the GUI, you may resize the window based on the number of items using code like

```
pos = get(gcf, 'position');
set(gcf, 'position', [ pos(1:3) pos(4)*nItems]);
```

You would also resize your GUI within the window. Let say h is the handle of the container in which you put your text and that it only shows one item. You change the text and now want to resize the GUI and keep the size of the figure the same.

```
pos = get(h, 'extent');
set(h, 'extent', [ pos(1:3) pos(4)*nItems]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of a figure window by changing its `'Position'` property. The first two values are the x and y coordinates of the bottom-left corner (w.r.t. the bottom-left corner of the screen), and the last two values are the width and height. This property can be read to obtain the current position and size. For example:

```
h = figure; % this is where you create you GUI in
h.Position(3) = 50; % set the width to 50 pixels.
```

If you want to use a different unit of measurements, instead of the default pixels, set the `'Units'` property:

```
h.Units = 'characters'; % now the position will be given in relation to the size of the font.
```

Other possible units include `'centimeters'`, `'inches'` and `'points'`.

Comment: Actually I need to get the information for GUI window. Which variable has matlab GUI position information?

Comment: @sanmiyom: GUIs are built inside figure windows. `gcf` will return a handle to the active figure window (the last to be displayed, or the last you interacted with).

Comment: Actually, I still struggle with this situation. I will type the inputnames on the text buttons. But how can I adjust static text box's width according to the inputname? I will set all  static text widths according to the inputname with the largest length.

Comment: You typed 'now the position will be given in relation to the size of the font'. But it does not adjust it according to its font.

Comment: @sanmiyom: No, fitst you set the font size, then you set the units to “characters”, then you set the window size. MATLAB will not adjust the window size when you change the font. But with units set to “characters” you can give sizes in characters rather than pixels, so your code becomes independent of font size.